# accessing contents of a void pointer holding a C++ object in C

Tags: c++, c, instrumentation

I'm doing binary instrumentation with [DynamoRIO](http://www.dynamorio.org/) using a C client on a C++ program **although you probably don't need to know about DynamoRIO to answer my question.** Currently I'm wrapping a function which has a signature:

```
virtual void foo(Klass& s)
```

And then in the wrap function I can get the argument of this function call (`Klass& s`) to a void pointer (`void *arg1`). I need to make use of this argument (i.e accessing fields, calling methods), however I can't cast it to the appropriate pointer as `Klass` is a C++ class and the client I'm using is in pure C.

When I try to print contents of the `void*` by casting it to a `size_t` such as:

```
printf("%zd\n", (size_t)arg1);
```

it gives me an 8 digit number such as `25102856` which I'm guessing is a memory address.

**My question is how can I access this object in my program?**

Pls ask all the information you need, I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: I doubt this is at all possible.

Comment: C and C++ are well known for their structured memory usage. If you know the layout of class `Klass`, you can reinterpret the `void` memory in the same pattern that you created it in C++ by reading the appropriate sized chunks. This is similar to simple packet-sniffing techniques

Comment: But I'm going with H2CO3 on the calling methods stuff

Comment: @AK4749 yes, you can, but you're not supposed to because that's essntially UB.

Comment: @AK4749 I have been trying to dump the memory at the given location, but I can't access the corresponding memory location as it doesn't let me dereference a `void*`.

Comment: @gokcehan right, you're supposed to "*know*" what's there and dereference that type of data. However, I don't know how useful that is for you if you can't call the methods.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is it really UB? I thought C/C++ had explicit rules for member data layout in memory. Though with virtual functions, etc all bets are off of course. gokcehan, UB = undefined behavior

Comment: @AK4749 I was hoping to find some relevant information from the fields or even maybe symbol names.

Comment: @AK4749 no, it hasn't - the compiler is free to insert padding at undocumented places and `__attribute__((packed))` is nonstandard.

Comment: @H2CO3 interesting, I was unaware of that, thanks! (Though for full investigation purposes - do major compilers ever do that for "simple" classes?)

Comment: @AK4749 Yep, because memory alignment is good for fast member access. (Only if you knew what kind of 'optimizations' GCC does! E. g. if you call `printf()` with one single constant string, it will omit `printf()` and will call `puts()` instead!)

Comment: @H2CO3 ah, i see. So then overlaying a class onto that "void" memory only works because the compiler will make the same optimizations? I guess that's what's got me hung up. In which case there would be no way gokcehan could recover information unless he defined a struct with similar members, overlaid it and hoped the same optimization would happen?

Comment: @AK4749 Exactly. And even that doesn't happen because compilers are dumb or whatever, and not the same padding scheme is used for C structs and C++ classes.

Comment: @AK4749 I can't really create a similar struct in my program because that class I'm working on is quite complicated with fields of different objects. I would probably need to pull in the whole library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work - define C style wrappers for getter and setters, like in this example:

For your class

```
class Klass {
public:
  int getA() const;
  void setA(int);
  virtua int getB() const;
};
```

Define C structs which wraps this class:

```
typedef int (*GetInt)(void*);
typedef void (*SetInt)(void*,int);
// and similar for other types


struct KlassCInterface {
  void* object;
  GetInt getA;
  SetInt setA;
  GetInt getB;
};

extern "C" int getA(void* obj)
{
    return static_cast<Klass*>(klassObj)->getA();
}
...
KlassCInterface* getCInterface(Klass* obj)
{
   // malloc just in case your client want to use free()
   KlassCInterface* retVal = (KlassCInterface*)malloc(sizeof(KlassCInterface));
   retVal->object = obj;
   retVal->getA = &getA;
   ...
   return retVal;     
}
```

When you pass void* data, pass it as the C interface struct:

```
Klass* obj = new Klass(...);
KlassCInterface* objC = getCInterface(obj);

registerData(objC);
```

In your C code - use this C interface:

```
void doSthWihtKlass(void* data)
{
   KlassCInterface* objC  = (KlassCInterface*)data;
   printf("%d\n", objC->getA(objC->object));
}
```

Comment: This shadowing approach seems safer, but I don't think it achieves what the poster wants, since it works on a copy of the object (unless he _only_ wants to call `const` methods). Also, `malloc()`ing is surely overkill. Let the client pass in the result buffer.

Comment: Just an idea. Allocating memory is not a must - if lifetime of this data is controlled by C++ part not C part. An idea is to hide C++ interface not behind simple `void*` data, but also behind some "C" function defined in C++ code - thus it can have access to C++ objects interfaces.

Comment: +1 for the solution, however I'm not allowed to introduce modification to the `C++` application I'm tracing. hope I'm interpreting your correctly..

Comment: To be more specific - one question. What is relation between `void *arg1` and `Klass& s`? Is this just `void* arg = &s`?

Comment: hmmm, that's a good point actually. I don't really know as I'm just calling an API function from DynamoRIO which takes the position of the argument and returns a `void*`. How exactly does `C++` implements pass-by-reference?

Comment: In most cases this is implemented in identical way as passing pointer. Reference and pointers are the same in binary format - only syntax differs. So this is most probably pointer. Another question - do you know this `void*` is actually `Klass*`? If yes, can you link to your C part some C++ library with C interface? You can put in this library any necessary setters/getters by defining them as `extern "C"` like in my proposal.

Comment: well, I'm currently running my `C` program as a client inside DynamoRIO which doesn't allow me to do much. For example it usually segfaults whenever I use a library other than `libc`, so I highly doubt that would work.

Comment: How can DynamoRIO check your C program is pure C program without any C++ subpart? I do not know this library - either try or search DynamoRIO wiki/doc/groups if C++ is allowed... That's all I can advice.

Comment: there's actually an experimental `c++` support with the new version. I have been trying to make it work but it seems like another dead end (see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/DynamoRIO-Users/GkVL9IxxdnQ) if you want). I'm gonna have to find another way. Thanks for all the help.. (btw if you decide to post something again pls include my name with a `@` so I get a notifier)

Answer (score 1):

This should be difficult to do. You will have to know about the underlying C++ ABI. G++ implements [this](http://mentorembedded.github.com/cxx-abi/abi.html).

Usually, a C++ class is implemented much similarly to a structure in C. Roughly, base-class objects come in first, in the order of their declarations. Then, all other sub-objects of the class come in next, in the order of their declarations. This rule applies recursively to every enclosed object. Polymorphic objects will have a different layout, because more information must be stored; in particular, pointers to virtual methods, or a pointer to a structure containing these pointers, must be stored somewhere alongside the object.

Note that none of this is addressed by ISO 14882. Messing around with this is surely invoking undefined behavior.

With regards to calling virtual methods, you will have to look for the v-table. Once again, study the ABI from your compiler.

Comment: just a quick note, I'm not going to call a virtual method it's just I'm getting the object from a virtual method call. I will probably only need to call some getters.

Comment: In that case, most likely these methods are C-like functions (using some `thiscall` convention) with mangled names. The situation is far simpler. On the other hand, if you're calling _getters_, you could also access the underlying field directly.

Comment: That may also work for me but I can't even reach the object as it doesn't let me dereference a `void*`

Comment: Well, in that case, it is rather obvious you should be studying a little more of C and C++ before attempting your task. This is a very basic language issue you're supposed to know how to handle :)

Comment: can't you just give me a hint? I tried casting to `size_t`, `char*` or `int` yet it doesn't seem to work. Also tried `memcpy` but no luck..

Comment: Cast your `void*` pointer to `char*` and offset it. Or read about `offsetof()`. But, again, do study the language once again. It will be much more profitable for you instead of messing around with complicated things you don't quite understand yet.

Comment: I can't really use `offsetof` as it requires me to give it the type name which I don't have. Also how am I supposed to learn the language without doing stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn more about the pointer semantics (and this is what I think @Alek meant).

First of all, you can use the `%p` printf format specifier to print pointers directly. This will usually result in some helpful value, such as the memory location the pointer is pointing to.

You can cast the pointer to a `char *` and use it to read bytes directly off the memory. Or you can cast it to an `unsigned char *` and do a "hex dump" using `%x`. You can cast it to an `int *` and read an integer as represented by your C implementation - possibly a 4-byte 2's complement little endian signed integer on 8-bit bytes with no unused bits, for example.

`((unsigned long *)(((short *) ptr) + 7))[4]` will, for example, skip past a number of bytes equal to the size of 7 shorts plus the size of 4 unsigned longs and read an unsigned long from the memory location. Assuming the correct representation (as the C implementation expects) of an `unsigned long` was written to that exact memory location, you'll get its value.

Not only will you have to be sure, exactly, what is written where in the memory pointed to by `ptr` (which is why the ABI was mentioned), but also the resulting program will be unportable and subject to change/break at whim.

You may also need exact-width integer types as specified in the `<inttypes.h>` header.

Comment: it has been some time, but I think the problem was that I had `void*` to a `Klass*` and I was able to read the content of the `void*` but couldn't go any further. I know the basic pointer arithmetics although I usually have problems before it starts working. anyway this was going to be 'pushing too hard' with all those portabiliy issues as you said so I had given up. I'm trying something else now, thanks..